# Передача значений в функцию возврата

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

Изучая тему замыкания столкнулся со следующим примером, логика выполнения которого не до конца ясна. 

**Код функции**

```
function filter(arr, func) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var val = arr[i];

    if (func(val)) {
      result.push(val);
    }

  }

  return result;
}

function inBetween (a, b) {
    return function (x) {

        return x >= a && x <= b
    }

} 

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(filter(arr, inBetween(3, 6)));
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему аргумент вызова `func(val)` не добавляется как дополнительный аргумент `inBetween(a, b, val)`, а передается в значение аргумента `x` возвращаемой функции.

Каким образом выглядит lexical environment в момент вызова и передачи `val` в функцию `inBetween`?

**P.S:** Буду так же очень признателен если Вы сможете указать полезные источники где можно будет изучить данную более глубоко. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

неплохой пример, правда простоват но довольно наглядно https://habrahabr.ru/post/149526/

```js
function inBetween(a, b) {
  //каждая функция имеет свою область видимости, в данной области видимости после вызова сохранятся 2 переменные a,b;
  // и вернется функция которая принимает параметр x
  return function(x) {

    return x >= a && x <= b
  }

}

function filter(arr, func) {
  var result = [];
  // если в данном месте вывести console.log(func) то увидим следующее
  //function (x) {
  //     return x >= a && x <= b
  //}
  //
  // для JS это равносильно следующему
  //function (x) {
  //     var a = 3,b=6 -значения унаследованные из вышестоящей области видимости
  //
  //     return x >= a && x <= b
  //}
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var val = arr[i];

    if (func(val)) {
      result.push(val);
    }

  }

  return result;
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

document.write(inBetween(3, 6)(5)); //- в данном случае inBetween(3, 6) - вернула функцию куда мы сразу-же передали параметр x = 5
```